# Beautiful soup findAll returns empty list on this website?

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract property value history from this website:https://www.properly.ca/buy/home/view/ma-tEpHcSzeES-OlhE-V6A/bc/vancouver/1268-w-broadway-%23720/

But my code returns an empty list instead of the property cost history.

I used the following code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url= "https://www.properly.ca/buy/home/view/ma-tEpHcSzeES-OlhE-V6A/bc/vancouver/1268-w-broadway-%23720/"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
officials = soup.findAll("table",{"id":"property-history"})

for entry in officials:
    print(str(entry))
```

Which returns an empty list, although this URL does have a property history table. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ```py
> officials = soup.findAll("table",{"id":"property-history"})
> ```

On browser, I don't see a `table` with `id="property-history"` - but there *is* [a `div` with that `id`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCSzt.png), so maybe you can instead get the data you want through

```py
officials = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"property-history"})
```

<sub>Btw, the only `table` I could find while inspecting the page was [inside the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Brp.png), and I don't think it holds any useful information for you.</sub>